# Connecting to my Node.js app on heroku fails

Tags: node.js, qt, networking, heroku

I have written a simple server app in node js

```
var net = require('net')

console.log('start...')

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    console.log('client connected', socket.address())

    socket.on('end', function () {
        console.log('end: client disconnected')
    })
})

var port = process.env.PORT || 4713;

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('server is listening on port', port)
})
```

and a simple client in Qt:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>

#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTcpSocket socket;

    QObject::connect(&socket, static_cast<void(QTcpSocket::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError)>(&QTcpSocket::error),
            [](QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError) {
        qDebug() << "Error" << socketError;
    });

    QObject::connect(&socket, &QTcpSocket::stateChanged,
        [](QAbstractSocket::SocketState state) {
        qDebug() << state;
    });

    //socket.connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 4713);
    socket.connectToHost("herokutestoiaavb.herokuapp.com", 8080);

    QTimer::singleShot(2000, [&](){qDebug() << "disconnect now..."; socket.disconnectFromHost();});

    return a.exec();
}
```

It runs perfectly fine on my locale machine.

But when I deploy to heroku I can see that the app start and listens but I cannot connect.

I always getting a ConnectionRefusedError.

I think it has something to do with the port number. I tried 8080, 4713 and the port which heroku dynamically assigns to my app. But still getting the error.

> 2016-12-03T13:09:35.269234+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
>   2016-12-03T13:09:35.269243+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
>   2016-12-03T13:09:35.637820+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
>   2016-12-03T13:09:35.638412+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
>   2016-12-03T13:09:36.653298+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
>   2016-12-03T13:09:36.739735+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
>   2016-12-03T13:09:37.413979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node heroku.js`
>   2016-12-03T13:09:39.638158+00:00 app[web.1]: start...
>   2016-12-03T13:09:39.658419+00:00 app[web.1]: server is listening on port 15665
>   2016-12-03T13:09:41.138467+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
>   2016-12-03T13:09:41.108477+00:00 app[web.1]: client connected { address: '::ffff:172.17.101.182', family: 'IPv6', port: 15665 }
>   2016-12-03T13:09:41.112260+00:00 app[web.1]: end: client disconnected
>   2016-12-03T13:09:41.113445+00:00 app[web.1]: client connected { address: '::ffff:172.17.101.182', family: 'IPv6', port: 15665 }
>   2016-12-03T13:09:41.114384+00:00 app[web.1]: end: client disconnected
>   2016-12-03T13:11:05.571200+00:00 app[web.1]: client connected { address: '::ffff:172.17.101.182', family: 'IPv6', port: 15665 }
>   2016-12-03T13:11:05.572232+00:00 app[web.1]: end: client disconnected
>   2016-12-03T13:13:20.696667+00:00 app[web.1]: client connected { address: '::ffff:172.17.101.182', family: 'IPv6', port: 15665 }
>   2016-12-03T13:13:20.697078+00:00 app[web.1]: end: client disconnected
>   2016-12-03T13:15:35.879204+00:00 app[web.1]: client connected { address: '::ffff:172.17.101.182', family: 'IPv6', port: 15665 }
>   2016-12-03T13:15:35.879473+00:00 app[web.1]: end: client disconnected
>   2016-12-03T13:17:51.145281+00:00 app[web.1]: client connected { address: '::ffff:172.17.101.182', family: 'IPv6', port: 15665 }
>   2016-12-03T13:17:51.147231+00:00 app[web.1]: end: client disconnected
>   2016-12-03T13:20:05.676596+00:00 app[web.1]: client connected { address: '::ffff:172.17.101.182', family: 'IPv6', port: 15665 }
>   2016-12-03T13:20:05.676876+00:00 app[web.1]: end: client disconnected

I don't know what the connection from IP 172.17.101.182 is, but it's not me. A little bit strange...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to connect manually with netcat (the `nc` command)?

Comment: If I try this `ncat.exe herokutestoiaavb.herokuapp.com` I'm also getting connection refused error,

Comment: And netcat works fine for localhost? Then you've probably misconfigured something.js.